# openlayers 4.4 : join two sources to a clustering layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

in openlayers 4.4, how can I join two sources to a cluster source ?

```
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
distance: 20,
source: [administrationSource,empriseSource],
geometryFunction: clusterFunction
});
```

Comment: It could be done, but would need the features from the other sources to be preloaded  `source: new ol.source.Vector({ features: [].concat(administrationSource.getFeatures(), empriseSource.getFeatures()) }),`

Comment: HI,
problem is that the sources are not preloaded so getFeatures are empty

Comment: There's an addfeature event mentioned in the API. If it works as I would expect you should be able to add listeners to the sources and push new features through to the cluster `administrationSource.on('addfeature', function(event) { clusterSource.getSource().addFeature(event.feature); });`

Comment: thank you, I would have learned to cumulate two sources, but in this case, the sources also change with each movement of the extent. In short, it has become too complex to manage to refresh the clusterLayer too. I will gather the data upstream in postgresql and load them into a single layer.